# Preprocess Menu Link Independent of menu.html.twig?

Tags: 8, hooks

I am hoping there is a way to alter a menu link independent of `menu.html.twig`

Motivation is this example from Bootstrap theme **menu.html.twig**:

```
{% set link_title = item.title %}
{% set link_title %}{{ link_title }} <span class="caret"></span>{% endset %}
```

The Twig template is adding markup to the link `$variables['text']` of `hook_link_alter()`.

I'm altering the text of a menu link item but retaining any HTML it might have. I have the below which works:

```
function hook_link_alter(&$variables) {

  $linkText = $variables['text'];
  $cleanLinkText = rtrim(strip_tags($linkText));

  if ($cleanLinkText == 'string') {

    $linkMarkup = str_replace($cleanLinkText, '', $linkText);

    // c_Markup() returns a new TranslatableMarkup().
    // We have to pass back in the HTML.
    $markup = c_Markup($linkMarkup);

    $variables['text'] = $markup;

  }

}
```

Things like `str_replace` and `trim` are very powerful, but I would prefer I use the appropriate hook for the need.

Have worked with `hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook)` without better success.

---

Update: This also works and I am able to get the text without the markup. Yet it seems like a lot more work to cycle through all the entire menu tree.

```
function hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {

  foreach ($variables['items'] as &$key) {

    $title = rtrim(strip_tags($key['title']));

    if ($title == 'string') {

      $key['title'] = $markup;

    }

    foreach ($key['below'] as &$beKey) {

      if ($beTitle == 'string') {

        $beKey['title'] = $markup;

      }

    }

  }

}
```

I guess this answers my question but is there a more direct hook/method to use? Under `$key['original_link']` I can see the protected Translatable Markup for the link title.